# How to add post thumbnail on posts on sites homepage?

Tags: post-thumbnails, homepage, theme-twenty-seventeen

I am using 2017 theme and I want to thumbnail to the posts which appears on my site homepage, thumbnail appearing when we visit post but doesn't appear on homepage[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to create a child theme so that when changes are made to 2017 theme and you update your theme with repository, your changes are not lost.

[How to create a child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

Then go to the theme folder/template-parts/post/content.php

Approx edit line 54 to add native function get_the_post_thumbnail(); to div.entry-content

below is the code

```
<div class="entry-content">
        <?php
        get_the_post_thumbnail();
        /* translators: %s: Name of current post */
        the_content( sprintf(
            __( 'Continue reading<span class="screen-reader-text"> "%s"</span>', 'twentyseventeen' ),
            get_the_title()
        ) );

        wp_link_pages( array(
            'before'      => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyseventeen' ),
            'after'       => '</div>',
            'link_before' => '<span class="page-number">',
            'link_after'  => '</span>',
        ) );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

Comment: Is this the default Wordpress twenty seventeen theme?

Comment: Could you a link if it is live on a server?

Comment: http://rahulpalve.ml/

Comment: I am using advance twenty seventeen plug-in to use features of child theme

Comment: Just add <?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ) ); ?> to your code markup code 

``<header class="entry-header">
    <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ) ); ?>">
</header>``

Comment: Thanks for your response to my questions, I added the code as you mentioned above but this create two thumbnail on my posts. That is not my problem my problem is that thumbnail appear on post but doesn't appear on homepage of my site.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin has an option that fixes this problem without needing a child theme https://wordpress.org/plugins/options-for-twenty-seventeen/